# How can I return the property of a domain object in a Grails search?

Tags: grails, model-view-controller, grails-orm

I am writing my own search for a rather small project. The search page consists of g:selects populated by domain object fields like so:

```
<g:form action="list" method="GET">
Last Name <g:select id="lastName" name="searchedLName" from="${StudentEntry.list(sort:lastName, order:desc)}"
        noSelection="['null':'None']" optionValue="lastName" value="${params.searchedLName}"/><br/> 
Submitted By <g:select id="submitter" name="searchedSubmitter" from="${UserAuth.list(sort:userName, order:desc)}"
        noSelection="['null':'None']" optionValue="userName" value="${params.searchedSubmitter}"/><br/>
<button id="submitIt" type="submit">Search</button>
```

Here is a snippet of the domain object

```
class StudentEntry {
     String firstName
     String lastName
     String submittedBy

String toString() {
    lastName + ", " + firstName
}
```

Here is some bootstrap data

```
def entry1 = new StudentEntry {
     firstName: "John"
     lastName: "Smith"
     submittedBy: "Jane Doe"
}

def entry2 = new StudentEntry {
     firstName: "James"
     lastName: "Jones"
     submittedBy: "Jane Doe"
}
```

Here is the code for list from the StudentEntryController

```
def list(params) {
    def result

    println "Searched Last Name: " + params?.searchedLName
    def theLastName = params?.searchedLName
    println "Searched Last Name: " + theLastName

    println "Searched Submitter: " + params?.searchedSubmitter
    def theSubmitter = params?.searchedSubmitter
    println "Searched Submitter: " + theSubmitter

    if(params) {
       result = StudentEntry.findAllWhere(lastName: theLastName, submitter: theSubmitter)
//render...
```

When I run the search, the println statements are outputting the toString method of the StudentEntry class of the domain object associated with the selected value. For example, if I search for lastName="Jones", the println will output `Searched Last Name: Jones, James`. My render method returns an empty list when I want to see the entry of James Jones.

What is the correct way to pass the property of the object instead of the object itself to the findAllWhere method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I neglected to specify the field that I want to search on as the `optionKey`attribute in the g:select. The `println` statements are now outputting the desired data.